# How can I restart pf in OpenBSD?

Tags: services, openbsd

I want to restart pf service after some edits in my `/etc/pf.conf` but

```
rcctl restart pf
```

does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't restart `pf`, you merely reload the ruleset with

```
pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

Actually, `pf` isn't a daemon to be started or stopped.  Besides reloading the ruleset you can disable it (`pfctl -d`) or enable it (`pfctl -e`).  See `man pfctl` for all the details and more good stuff from `pfctl` (e.g. statistics).

Comment: But `pf` appears in `/etc/conf.d` isn't? It's a strange it is not a service but it appears in that file.

Comment: Do you mean `/etc/rc.conf.local`? The whole "daemon" vs. "service" thing is not very clear, not in even in OpenBSD's docs (BTW, checkout `man /etc/rc.conf`). In my answer I considered a daemon something that runs as a separate process (hence being started/stopped) while `pf` is a part of the kernel, so it can be turned on/off, instead of started/stopped which is something _I_ associate mostly with processes.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `/etc/rc.conf`.

Comment: So, no all process are treat equally (although they "seem" daemons) in OpenBSD

Comment: @somenxavier. Things like `pf`, multicast, IPSec, etc are configured on the same file as the daemons, yes, even if they "run" in the kernel, instead of a separate process.

Answer (score -5):

If the rcctl restart pf command is not working, it is possible that the pf service is not managed by rcctl on your system.

Here are a few things you can try:

1. Check the status of the `pf` service using the service command:
   bash

```bash
service pf status
```

This will show you the current status of the `pf` service. If it's not running, you can start it with the following command:

```bash
service pf start
```

2. Check if `pf` is enabled to start at boot:
   bash

```bash
rcctl get pf
```

If the output is `pf=NO`, you can enable it to start at boot with the following command:

```bash
rcctl enable pf
```

3. Restart the entire system to ensure that the changes take effect. This is a good idea if you have made significant changes to the pf.conf file.

If none of these steps work, it could be that your system uses a different method to manage the pf service. In that case, [you should consult your system's documentation or administrator for further guidance](https://www.openbsdhandbook.com/).

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with OpenBSD, but does it have a `service` command?

Comment: Yes, OpenBSD does have a service command that can be used to manage services on the system (i.e.: `service <service_name> start`), but do note that OpenBSD uses its own init system called `rc`. 
The `service` command is a frontend to **rcctl**, which is the actual tool that manages services on OpenBSD, so you can also use rcctl directly to manage services on OpenBSD `rcctl start <service_name>`

Comment: OpenBSD does **not** have a `service` command (not in the base installation, at least).

Comment: Your answer could be useful for FreeBSD (which has `service` command), perhaps